# Examples of rings whose ideals are all nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for examples.

> **Definition 1.** Let $R$ a ring, an element $x\in R$ is said to be *nilpotent* if exists $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $x^n=0$.
>
> **Definition 2.** An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is said to be *nil ideal* if each element $x\in I$ is nilpotent.
>
> **Definition 3.** An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is said *nilpotent* if $I^n=\{0\}$ for same $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$.

Could someone give me some examples of a ring whose ideals are all nilpotent?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want just the proper ideals to be idempotent?

Comment: Yes! I would like to rings whose proper ideals are nilpotent

Comment: A lame class of examples are fields :) the only proper ideal in a field is the zero ideal, which is nilpotent

Comment: Examples of rings (necessarily without identity) having *all* ideals nilpotent are also not hard to think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, take $k$ a field and consider $k[x] / x^n$.  Show that this ring has a maximum (proper) ideal generated by $x$.  Thus $I^n =0$ for all $I \subset k[x] / x^n$.

More generally, if every proper ideal of a ring is nilpotent, then every nonunit element is nilpotent.  This happens precisely when the ring has exactly one prime ideal.  Note that a finitely generated ideal is nilpotent iff its generators are.

So a class of rings satisfying this property are **local Artinian rings**.

Comment: The first line of the second paragraph seems to assume commutativity, which hasn't been mentioned yet. Pretty sure the third sentence is commutativity dependent too. Not a complaint, just noting the unstated assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly $\mathbb{Z}/ p^n\mathbb{Z}$ should have that property, since it has only subgroups of the form $\mathbb{Z}/ p^k\mathbb{Z}$ for $k<n$, which are generated by $p^l$ for some $l$. In particular, those are the ideals, and all of those are nilpotent, since their generators are clearly nilpotent

Comment: @EnkiduThanks for your answer. Sorry, but I did not understand your example!

Comment: Just calculate the ideals and the powers in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for some choice of $p$ and $n$, for example if you are lazy: $p=2$ and $n=2$.